# Xcode error: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift

I know you seen this error alot of times as did I, 
but I tried every solution I found and non of them worked for me

I updated my `Xcode` to the last version `10.2.1`.
I updated the `cocoapods` and the pods in the project.
I even tried to lock and unlock the `keychain Access`.

I don't know what to do now, this is the last solution I got to ask you here.

Comment: What else is written in the text of the error?

Comment: @Booharin /Users/mohammedGhm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JAWAKOrganizers-eykecwkbwqxyqxdimyidhrmvjsxi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/JAWAKOrganizers.build/Debug-iphoneos/JAWAKOrganizers.build/Script-9CE28B14649F2C34CE4AAD65.sh: line 2: /Users/mohammedGhm/Downloads/JAWAKOrganizers/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-JAWAKOrganizers/Pods-JAWAKOrganizers-frameworks.sh: Permission denied
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Xcode -> Prefernces -> Locations -> Remove DerivedData

Comment: @Booharin it's set to Default. should I delete the folder in the path ?

Comment: yes, delete the folder in the path

Comment: @Booharin nope didn't work

Comment: Please don't add stuff like `solved` in pretty much any form or using any synonyms. It's not how SO is intended to work - this isn't a forum.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> and clean the project.

Comment: already tried that, sadly didn't worked for me